# Formulário PHP + HTML com select Restritivo

Tags: php, css, html5

Saudações.
Estou iniciando nesta área de dev e entrei em um desafio de desenvolver um Formulário restritivo.

Em que consiste?

- neste exemplo simples utilizarei 3 selects

1 validação de condição
option value = "AM"
option value = "PM"

2 - Contendo horários referente a manhã
exemplo 
option value = "01:00"
option value = "02:00"
option value = "03:00"
option value = "04:00"

3 - Contendo horários referente a tarde/noite
option value = "13:00"
option value = "14:00"
option value = "15:00"
option value = "16:00"

Quando for selecionado no primeiro select a opção AM, a aplicação chama o Select referente a manhã e quando selecionarmos a opção PM, faremos o mesmo com o outro formulário.

Me ajudem por favor.

Utilizo PHP, HTML e CSS.
alguma luz que alguém pode me dar ? 
Desde já obrigado pela atenção.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Você terá de usar javascript ou JQuery para ficar mais fácil, com PHP teria de ficar alternado as páginas para cada select.

Primeiro você deve criar os 3 select`s na página
Após isso ocultar os 2 referentes as horas com a propriedade display: none; no CSS

e ao selecionar AM ou PM o javascript da um display: block; no elemento para aparecer

Aqui está https://jsfiddle.net/4cwpvapg/

Comment: Felipe. Muito obrigado pelo auxílio.  Era exatamente isso :)